# Prepend modal-backdrop to div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a container that I want everything to sit within.

At the moment the default behavior for when triggering a modal is that it generates a div with class of "modal-backdrop" and prepends it to the body of the document, I want to prepend it to a div instead of the body but can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: can u provide any fiddle or plunker

Comment: Hi sorry I can't at the moment, I know I've done it before, ages ago but I can't remember how, something with some jquery that basically changed where the modal-backdrop was positioned when initialised. So that instead of just going before the closing body tag it was before the closing div.